# How to make a webview scrollable in tabbarwiew in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I've spent almost two days trying to figure out how to make a webview scrollable in a tabbarview in Flutter. I understand that the TabBarWiew Widget should be wrapped in a fixed height widget, what can be a workaround for this? 
I don't know if it can help but my **minSdkVersion is 16 and targetSdkVersion is 28**,
And this is the output of **flutter --version** command

```
Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 27321ebbad (10 weeks ago) • 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
Engine • revision 2994f7e1e6
Tools • Dart 2.7.0
```

Below is the code for the page I'm building.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Pays'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.

    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
      Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
      Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
    ];

    TabController _tabController;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      _tabController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[800],
      ),
      body: Container(
          color: Colors.grey[100],
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: Image.network(
                    'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/dThF-49TD0synkY_v1F0mh2HQFp_P5bxYvdLI1msK-aD7h4CtzctJpJP3Cm89LyAWAg21xqvUDdQjdRi2yDH4iEU1wr_LT3BO8iOmx141QOtzXPgUpXW7ulAlHUtAJ4Z0yea_Qr4sWZfApns3VuAbxNcTNISWdStSoJEZ9-OmRypu-3YTQ',
                    height: 150,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                  )),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 1,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('237',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 35,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Image.network(
                      'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJrM_W9cpz33KFyqL_L-meeCuH_Kyufoohxjlh06XdBnIbel0j&s',
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Image.network(
                      'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwnqIeW1RJHtAhRE7ccZ-4s4ymEh5zHRYAdidO7p9GfDnOwziY&s',
                      height: 50,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Cameroun',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )
                    ]),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              NestedTabBar()
            ],
          )),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class NestedTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NestedTabBarState createState() => _NestedTabBarState();
}

class _NestedTabBarState extends State<NestedTabBar>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _nestedTabController;
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //_scrollController = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
    _nestedTabController = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    //_nestedTabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nestedTabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TabBar(
          controller: _nestedTabController,
          indicatorColor: Colors.teal,
          labelColor: Colors.teal,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(
              text: "A propos & Statistiques",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Wiki",
            )
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          height: screenHeight * 0.9,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _nestedTabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text('Simple text')),

              /*GestureDetector(
                    child: MyWebView(selectedUrl: 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Hamilton'),
              ),*/

              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                child: MyWebView(
                    selectedUrl: 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cameroun'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        // MyWebView(selectedUrl: 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Hamilton')
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String selectedUrl;

  MyWebView({
    @required this.selectedUrl,
  });

  @override
  _MyWebViewState createState() => _MyWebViewState();
}

class _MyWebViewState extends State<MyWebView> {
  Completer<WebViewController> _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: WebView(
      initialUrl: widget.selectedUrl,
      gestureRecognizers: Set()
        ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
            () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
      gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview 
Step 1: change `Android minSdkVersion` to `17` 
Step 2: reference package with the following , because this issue. https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/220

```
flutter_inappwebview:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview.git
      ref: master
```

Step 3: code snippet

```
Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                child: InAppWebView(
                  initialUrl: "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Hamilton",
                  initialHeaders: {},
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Pays'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
      Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
      Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
    ];

    TabController _tabController;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      _tabController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[800],
      ),
      body: Container(
          color: Colors.grey[100],
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: Image.network(
                    'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/dThF-49TD0synkY_v1F0mh2HQFp_P5bxYvdLI1msK-aD7h4CtzctJpJP3Cm89LyAWAg21xqvUDdQjdRi2yDH4iEU1wr_LT3BO8iOmx141QOtzXPgUpXW7ulAlHUtAJ4Z0yea_Qr4sWZfApns3VuAbxNcTNISWdStSoJEZ9-OmRypu-3YTQ',
                    height: 150,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                  )),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 1,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('237',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 35,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Image.network(
                      'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJrM_W9cpz33KFyqL_L-meeCuH_Kyufoohxjlh06XdBnIbel0j&s',
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Image.network(
                      'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwnqIeW1RJHtAhRE7ccZ-4s4ymEh5zHRYAdidO7p9GfDnOwziY&s',
                      height: 50,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Cameroun',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )
                    ]),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              NestedTabBar()
            ],
          )),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class NestedTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NestedTabBarState createState() => _NestedTabBarState();
}

class _NestedTabBarState extends State<NestedTabBar>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _nestedTabController;
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  InAppWebViewController webView;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //_scrollController = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
    _nestedTabController = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    //_nestedTabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nestedTabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TabBar(
          controller: _nestedTabController,
          indicatorColor: Colors.teal,
          labelColor: Colors.teal,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(
              text: "A propos & Statistiques",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Wiki",
            )
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          height: screenHeight * 0.9,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _nestedTabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text('Simple text')),

              /*GestureDetector(
                    child: MyWebView(selectedUrl: 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Hamilton'),
              ),*/

              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                child: InAppWebView(
                  initialUrl: "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Hamilton",
                  initialHeaders: {},
                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                      )
                  ),
                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    webView = controller;
                  },
                  onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url;
                    });
                  },
                  onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url;
                    });
                  },
                  onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.progress = progress / 100;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        // MyWebView(selectedUrl: 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Hamilton')
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add gestureRecognizers as a WebView parameter:

```
WebView(
  gestureRecognizers: {
    Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
            () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()
    )
  },
  initialUrl: widget.url,
);
```

As mentioned here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33565